# How do I get a DLink DWM 156 broadband modem working?

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, broadband, usb-modem

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enabling or Installing D-Link DWM 156 in 12.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168663/enabling-or-installing-d-link-dwm-156-in-12-04-lts)

I just bougth D-link DWM 156 usb modem and having a problem to have it works with ubuntu i had done edit connection, and then insert mobile broadband info, and after that i dunno what to do..

I do lsusb and i found this:

**Bus 002 Device 003: ID 2001:a80b D-Link Corp.**

I check in the properties and my modem is detected as a CD drive, how can i change it to modem